# How insert data to Cassandra DB via library php?

Tags: php, cassandra

I use *Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library library* for get/set data to Apache Cassandra.
I created a keyspace name via **cqlsh** coomanda line:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  company text,
  name text,
  age int,
  role text,
  PRIMARY KEY (company,name)
);
```

Then have inserted some columns also via command line:

```
INSERT INTO employees (company, name, age, role) VALUES ('OSC', 'eric', 38, 'ceo');
INSERT INTO employees (company, name, age, role) VALUES ('OSC', 'john', 37, 'dev');
```

Now I try insert any data from php, for this i use method **set()** of library:

```
$this->cassandra->set(
            'employees.company',
            array(
                'company' => 'alicerozenberg@gmail.com',
                'name'    => 'Alice Rozenberg',
                'age'     => 45,
                'role'    => 'ddd'
            )
        );
```

In the official manual was told that **first** param of function set() is key row (employees is a name of column family, company is a key), and **other** - are name and value of columns.
In this regard, I have a few questions:

What is a **row key** in my case? At the "CREATE" command I specifed, that primary key is "company,name". But this not correct for use in function. This option does not work:

```
$this->cassandra->set(
                'employees.name',
...

$this->cassandra->set(
                'employees.company',
...
```

**I change** to phpcassa library and have question about composites types:

From tutorial example:
https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/examples/composites.php

```
// Insert a few records
$key1 = array("key", 1);
$key2 = array("key", 2);

$columns = array(
    array(array(0, "a"), "val0a"),

    array(array(1, "a"), "val1a"),
    array(array(1, "b"), "val1b"),
    array(array(1, "c"), "val1c"),

    array(array(2, "a"), "val2a"),

    array(array(3, "a"), "val3a")
);
```

Who can me tell, what composire array will be in my case for two row keys "name, company"? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY (company,name)
```

Compound primary keys in Cassandra have multiple parts.  The first column (`company` in your case) is your [partitioning key](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/share/glossary/gloss_partition_key.html).  This is the key that will help determine which partition the row is stored on.

The next part of a compound primary key, are the [clustering columns](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html).  The clustering columns indicate the on-disk sort order of your data.  In your case, you only have one clustering column (`name`).  Your row data will then be stored by a (assumed unique) combination of `company` and `name`, and your data will be sorted (on-disk) by `name`.

> What is a row key in my case?

The **row key** in your case is this combination of both `company` and `name`.

Now how do you set that in your PHP (PHPCassa?) code?  I'm not exactly sure.  But from what I'm reading on this blog posting (*warning: it is a couple of years old*) titled [Cassandra PHPCassa & Composite Types](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/2012/03/cassandra-phpcassa-composite-types.html), you may need to define your rowkey as an array, like this:

```
$this->cassandra->set(
        array('employees.company','employees.name'),
        array(
            'age'     => 45,
            'role'    => 'ddd'
        )
    );
```

Try that and see if it helps.  Otherwise, reference the article I linked above.

Based on your most-recent edit, I think your key definition will look something like this:

```
$key = array("alicerozenberg@gmail.com", "Alice Rozenberg");
$columns = array(45,"ddd");
$cf->insert($key, $columns);
```

Comment: Thank you for extended response. But I use not phpcassa library. However, I tried your solution, it does not work. The script show fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CassandraInvalidPatternException' with message 'Unable to set "Array", expected the column family name andkey name seperated by a fullstop' in...

Comment: So, i will change my library to phpcassa, see there are more options

Comment: @Alice Setting your key as an array didn't work?  There must be some way to do it with your library.

Comment: I changed to phpcassa library and edited my question

Comment: From here is object **$cf** and why instead keys there is array **$key** of values?